# For each pair in the list decide with proof if the groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a question in my list of exercises and there is nothing in my lecture notes about it, and we havent done an example of anything similar. I missed a workshop due to illness so I fear I may have missed it.

But basically for each pair in the list decide with proof if the groups are isomorphic:

(a) $C_2 \times C_6$
(b) $C_4 \times C_3$
(c) $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$

I'm not really sure where to start.
(a) $C_2 \times C_6$
(b) $C_4 \times C_3$

Considering $C_2, C_6$, $C_4, C_3$ they are all cyclic and all Abelian.
$C_3$ is simple.

All I can think is that $C_6$ has a subgroup of order 3 and the others don't so it's not isomorphic, is that even remotely right? And how would I go about proving it?

Thank you. Please explain in layman's terms!

Comment: What you need is in this paragraph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Properties. And is basically the chinese remainder theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem Also, you probably have a typo: there is most likely a 3 among these three 2's in (c)

Comment: Careful: of the three given groups, *only* one is cyclic...

Comment: Just what I was going to add, @DonAntonio!

Comment: @DonAntonio, I meant that C_2, C_6, C_4 and C_3 are all cyclic.

Comment: Then write **that**, @Emily ...

Answer (score 1):

HINT: What is the order of the element $\langle 1,1\rangle$ in $C_4\times C_3$? What is the maximum order of any element of $C_2\times C_6$?

Comment: I don't know how I would work that out

Comment: @Emily: Which part? The first is just a matter of adding $\langle 1,1\rangle$ to itself repeatedly to see how long it takes to reach $\langle 0,0\rangle$.

Comment: so would you do it first for C_4 then C_3, so the order of <1,1> is 12?
And the maximum order of an element in C_2xC_6 is 12 also?

Comment: @Emily: You don’t have separate groups $C_4$ and $C_3$; you do it in the group $C_4\times C_3$. $\langle 1,1\rangle+\langle 1,1\rangle=\langle 2,2\rangle$; $\langle 2,2\rangle+\langle 1,1\rangle=\langle 3,0\rangle$; $\langle 3,0\rangle+\langle 1,1\rangle=\langle 0,1\rangle$; and so on.

Comment: order of <1,1> is 12?

Comment: @Emily: Yes, it is, so $C_4\times C_3$ is isomorphic to $C_{12}$. Now look at $\langle a,b\rangle\in C_2\times C_6$. What do you get if you add together six copies of it?

Comment: oh <1,1> has order 6 in C2XC6 so its not isomorphic to C12?

Comment: @Emily: You can’t quite make that jump: there might conceivably be some other element of $C_2\times C_6$ of order $12$. However, if you add six copies of any $\langle a,b\rangle$, you get $$\langle 6a\bmod 2,6b\bmod 6\rangle=\langle 0,0\rangle\;,$$ so no element of $C_2\times C_6$ can possibly have order more than $6$.

Comment: do we know that = <0,0> because C2 and C6 are cyclic?

Comment: @Emily: Yes: $C_2$ is cyclic of order $2$, so $a+a=0$ for all $a\in C_2$, and $C_6$ is cyclic of order $6$, so $a+a+a+a+a+a=0$ for each $a\in C_6$.

Comment: Okay I understand that bit now, but why can there be no element with order greater than 6? Or is that just because we are dealing with c2 and specifically C6?

Comment: @Emily: Because I just showed that adding together six copies of any element gives you the identity. The order of an element is the smallest positive number needed to give you the identity, so if $6$ do so, the order cannot be any more than that. In particular, there’s no element of order $12$, as there was in $C_4\times C_3$, so the two groups cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Of course yes, sorry I was being really thick then. Sorry for needing such a step by step answer.
So would I say that for C4 X C3;
<12amod4,12bmod3>=<0,0>
so C4XC4 is isomorphic to C12, but ⟨6amod2,6bmod6⟩=⟨0,0⟩is not isomorphic to C12 as there cannot be any element of order greater than six, hence C2XC6 is not isomorphic to C4XC3

Comment: @Emily: That’s right. $C_4\times C_3$ is actually a cyclic group itself, while $C_2\times C_6$ isn’t, since no single element generates the whole group.

Comment: is what I said above enough to *prove* that they are not isomorphic?
Also, C2XC6 isnt cyclic because there is no element of order 12 as the biggest is order 6 is that correct?

Comment: @Emily: Not quite: in $C_4\times C_3$ you have to show that $\langle 1,1\rangle$ really is of order $12$, i.e., that no smaller number will work. It’s perfectly acceptable simply to write out the $\langle 1,1\rangle$, $\langle 1,1\rangle+\langle 1,1\rangle$, etc. to show that it takes $12$ of them to get you the identity. Or you can be a little more clever and observe that if $\langle a\bmod 4,a\bmod 3\rangle=\langle 0,0\rangle$, then $a$ must be a multiple of $4$ **and** of $3$, so it must be at least $12$. Notice that $12$ is the least common multiple of $4$ and $3$, while $6$ is the ...

Comment: ... least common multiple of $2$ and $6$; you don’t need it for this problem, but you should try to see why the largest order of any element of $C_m\times C_n$ is the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Does this method work for all questions of this type?
Exactly why do you have to show that (1,1) is of order 12 in C4XC3 but not do similar for C2XC6?

Comment: @Emily: Showing that two groups are or are not isomorphic can be much more difficult than this. However, if you can show that a group $G$ has an element of order $m$, while group $H$ has no such element, then you’ve definitely proved that $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic. And if you’re looking specifically at groups of the form $C_m\times C_n$, this approach is certainly the place to start (well, after checking the cardinalities of the groups).

Comment: Thank you ever so much, sorry to bother you so much. It is really helping me.
What about if I were to consider C2XC6 and c2xc2xc3 is it the same approach?

Comment: @Emily: You’re welcome. You can actually be a little sneakier with that one: show that $C_2\times C_3$ is cyclic of order $6$, hence isomorphic to $C_6$, and then note that $C_2\times (C_2\times C_3)\cong C_2\times C_6$.

Comment: Is it enough to say that for C2xC3; <6amod2,6bmod3>=<0,0> so C2XC3 is cyclic of order 6?

Comment: @Emily: No, that just shows that every element of the group has an order that divides $6$ — which we knew anyway from Lagrange’s theorem, since the group has $6$ elements. Treat it the way you did $C_4\times C_3$: show that $\langle 1,1\rangle$ generates the whole group. When you keep adding $\langle 1,1\rangle$ to itself, you get elements $\langle m\bmod 2,m\bmod 3\rangle$; what’s the smallest positive integer $m$ for which this is the identity $\langle 0,0\rangle$?

Comment: would i be right to say m=6?

Comment: @Emily: Yes, because $6$ is the least common multiple of $2$ and $3$, the smallest positive integer that is a multiple of both of them. That means that the order of $\langle 1,1\rangle$ is $6$, and since the group has only $6$ elements, that means that $\langle 1,1\rangle$ generates the group. But then the group is cyclic of order $6$, which means that it’s isomorphic to $C_6$.

Comment: okay, and comparing the final 2,
C4XC3 and C2XC2XC3
from the part we just did we know C2XC2XC3 is isomorphic to C2XC6 and from the first part we said C4XC3 is isomorphic to C2XC6, hence
C4XC3 is isomorphic to C2XC2XC3?

Comment: @Emily: Whoa: we said that $C_4\times C_3$ is **not** isomorphic to $C_2\times C_6$. The former has an element of order $12$, and the latter doesn’t. Thus, $C_4\times C_3$ is not isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2\times C_3$, either.

Comment: oh yes sorry i read my notes wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(1)\;\;\;C_m\times C_n\cong C_{mn}\;\;\text{if}\;\;(m,n)=1$$

The above solves (a)-(b), and about (c): it doesn't even have the same order as the other two groups!